# accordion, tab menus, assign select class for both

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, tabs, accordion

I have two menus: the Accordion menu and Tab menu, for the Tab menu, there is an assigned class selected to a link that is opened, I want to assign the class (for example) open_menu, in the same way for the accordion menu. actually if the class open_menu will be given from the condiotion that in its ul there is an A link with class Selected, it would be much better, because the class selected given to a link is taken from the cookies, and even if the page is refreshed it comes to this link Selected. Anyway, u can see all the source here: http://jsfiddle.net/bq6tA/6/
actually the end product i want, after the refresh of the page, there will be opened the accordion's tab, as well as the Tab's menu link selected that is in this accordion's tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### See a working demo of the following code here.

I've modified your `initMenu` function to add the `open_menu` class to the appropriate accordion (and added a CSS class to indicate that it was added by changing the background to green):

```
function initMenu() {
    // SNIP ...
    $('#menu li a').click(function() {
        // SNIP ...
        if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $('#menu ul:visible').slideUp('normal')
                                 .siblings('a').removeClass('open_menu');
            checkElement.slideDown('normal')
                        .siblings('a').addClass('open_menu');
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I then created a function to be called after `initMenu` that will trigger a click on the accordion with the same `rel` as the `id` of the currently selected item:

```
function showCurrentTab() {
    var curId = $('.tabcontent:visible')[0].id,
        $curLink = $('a[rel="'+curId+'"]');

    $curLink.closest('ul')
            .parent('li')
            .children('a').click();
}
```

To figure out what's going on here, see the API docs for [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) and relate that to your HTML structure.

Comment: is it possible for the class menu_open, not be gone, coz when i push on the tab menu link, the class open_menu is disappear :(