# tab menu + accordion menu assign classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, tabs, accordion

I have asked question about these two menus before, but the subject was a bit different, for now, all i want is to upgrade the previous code written here: [accordion, tab menus, assign select class for both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836433/accordion-tab-menus-assign-select-class-for-both/4838175#4838175) so that the class open_menu doesnt disappear after i click the link in it's sub menu, u can easily understand it from this script: http://jsfiddle.net/bq6tA/11/ in comments i tried to reply the man who wrote this script, but he didn't reply, but i really need to modify this script, right now, and thx for help everyone!
btw, if i refresh the page, the classes are assigned ok, once i click the sub menu link, the class open_menu for top menu link disappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line 86 of tabcontent.js is looping through every item in your list structure and removing all styling classes if they're not the currently selected item:

```
this.getselectedClassTarget(this.tabs[i]).className=(this.tabs[i].getAttribute("rel")==subcontentid)? "selected" : ""
```

Add an additional click binder to reapply it for each lowest level item:

```
$("ul.reset a").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("ul").siblings("a").addClass("open_menu");
});
```

[**See a working demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/lthibodeaux/qgQXE/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helped me! Your are the best! :)

Comment: and the last update, and it will work perfect, erase the `$('#menu ul:first').show();` otherwise the class of tab menu 1 after refresh disappear, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qgQXE/1/

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply remove the `.removeClass('open_menu')` from the code?

Comment: it will not help, there will be then 2 or more links with one class open_menu

Comment: So, why do you need to remove the class then?

Comment: it should remove when u select another accordion menu, not sub menu, it actually have to disapper, but not when i click it's sub menu link